# jee:jndi-lookup OR JndiObjectFactoryBean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have  a JNDI Resource Set on Tomcat

```
<Context>
    ...  <Resource 
   name="jdbc/UserDB" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" 
        url="jdbc:db2://192.168.18.128:50000/USER"
        username="username" 
        password="password" 
        maxWait="10000" 
        maxIdle="30" 
        maxActive="100"/>
    ...
</Context>
```

then I use Two methods get JNDI Resource

methods_A jee:jndi-lookup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
 ...
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/UserDB" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
  ...
</beans>
```

methods_B JndiObjectFactoryBean

```
    <bean id="dataSourceUaa" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/UserDB"/>
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

But methods_B doesn't work

Must be changed

```
        <bean id="dataSourceUaa" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/UserDB"/>
            <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
        </bean>
```

It can work

sorry my question as follows

Which one should I choose?

Why is the JNDI difference?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Why is the JNDI difference?

Comment: Because they are different. You aren't comparing the same situation. Your `jndi-lookup` has a `proxy-interface` your other one hasn't. Which changes the way things are resolved.

Comment: @M.Deinum 
I tried to add <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>  for methods_B 。 The methods_B doesn't work

Comment: You should also set the `resourceRef` to `true`. This will, if `jdbc/UserDB`fails to be detected, fallback to `java:comp/env/jdbc/UserDB`.

Comment: @ M. Deinum Thank you I set <property name="resourceRef" value ="true"/>,   methods_B Normal Work like    methods_A